# Pyspark read multiple csv files into a dataframe in order

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

When I try to read a fold containing multiple CSV files by pyspark(2.2.1) into a dataframe, the data records are in an unexpected order. The data folder is created by another Spark program, and the files are like

```
/path/part-00000-*
/path/part-00001-*
......
```

and each file contains only one record. Some of the records have null values in some columns.

Records should be ordered by one column, and I'm sure that the files are in the right order, i.e., part-00000-* contains the first record, part-00001-* contains the second record...

However, when I read the data into dataframe by pyspark:

```
df = SQLContext(sc).read.format('csv')
    .option('header', 'true')
    .option('mode', 'DROPMALFORMED')
    .load('/path')
```

the order has been changed(the data should be ordered by column `timestamp`). I notice that the records on the top do not have null values:

```
+--------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|                time|  timestamp|         attr1|         attr2|
+--------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|2018-09-30 21:33:...| 1538314433| 1538314433000| 1538314433000|
|2018-09-30 21:35:...| 1538314544| 1538314544000| 1538314544000|
|2018-09-30 21:38:...| 1538314682| 1538314682000| 1538314682000|
|2018-09-30 21:38:...| 1538314734| 1538314734000| 1538314734000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313912|          null| 1538313912000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313913|          null| 1538313913000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313914|          null| 1538313914000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313915|          null| 1538313915000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313932|          null| 1538313932000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313934| 1538313934000|          null|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313942|          null| 1538313942000|
|2018-09-30 21:25:...| 1538313943|          null| 1538313943000|
|2018-09-30 21:26:...| 1538314007|          null| 1538314007000|
|2018-09-30 21:27:...| 1538314026| 1538314026000|          null|
|2018-09-30 21:27:...| 1538314028|          null| 1538314028000|
|2018-09-30 21:27:...| 1538314029|          null| 1538314029000|
|2018-09-30 21:27:...| 1538314043| 1538314043000|          null|
|2018-09-30 21:27:...| 1538314064| 1538314064000|          null|
|2018-09-30 21:27:...| 1538314067| 1538314067000|          null|
```

I'm wondering why this happened and how can I load a dataframe with right order.

Comment: you are on a distributed file system. Right order doesnt mean anything. You need to have a business rule to create the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to order by timestamp, just add the `orderBy` clause:

```
df.orderBy('timestamp').show()
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but I just want to know why the loaded data are disordered.

Comment: They are disordered because the behavior of a table is like a bag of marbles. You cant keep any order in the bag. You can create an artificial order when you pull out the marbles from the bag.

Comment: OK, I see, thx!
BTW, is there a way to specify the input order of multiple files?

Comment: it doesnt make sense. No matter the input order of your marbles in your bag, they wont keep that order after !